# sorting / splitting multidimensional array into many smaller

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I figured it out.. I'm only taking out $value[0], so off cause its only one result. Need more sleep. Thanks alot. I'm still open for suggestions to a cleaner way to split arrays.

I have an array `$tdata` with this structure:

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [firstName] => test
                [lastName] => test
                [userName] => test@test.com
                [password] => test
                [course] => test
                [role] => test
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [firstName] => test
                [lastName] => test
                [userName] => test@test.com
                [password] => test
                [course] => test
                [role] => test
            )

    )

    [delete] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [firstName] => test
                [lastName] => test
                [userName] => test@test.com
                [password] => test
                [course] => test
                [role] => test
            )

    )

    [update] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [firstName] => test
                [lastName] => test
                [userName] => test@test.com
                [password] => test
                [course] => test
                [role] => test
            )

    )

    [outrole] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [firstName] => test
                [lastName] => test
                [userName] => test@test.com
                [password] => test
                [course] => test
                [role] => test
            )

    )

)
```

I am trying to split it up into smaller arrays. Like this:

```
foreach ($tdata as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == '') {
       $create[] = $value[0];
    }elseif ($key == 'outrole') {
       $outrole[]  = $value[0];
    }elseif ($key == 'delete') {
       $delete[] = $value[0];
    }elseif ($key == 'update') {
       $update[] = $value[0];
    }else{
     $noaction[] = $value[0];
    }

}
```

This way the array keeps overwriting itself, I think. `print_r($create)` or any other of the arrays always returns only 1 result. Can enlighten me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

If there is a better way to do it I would love to hear that as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you only want the first item in each array?

Comment: Ahh thanks! I have steered myself blind.. Im only take out $value[0].. doh! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those keys are always present then you don't really need a loop:

```
$create = $original['create'];
$outrole = $original['outrole'];
```

You can add a check if they are set:

```
$create = isset($original['create']) ? $original['create'] : array();
```

This will set it to a blank array if it's not present.

Answer (score 1):

Your arrays are nested. To make smaller arrays you should iterate within inner values:

```
foreach ($tdata as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == '') {
       foreach($value as $subValue) {
           $create[] = $subValue;
       }
    }elseif ($key == 'outrole') {
       foreach($value as $subValue) {
           $outrole[] = $subValue;
       }
    } // ... and so on...        
}
```